# Using Typescript Variable to create img src

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array which contains a list of categories, below is an example of one category:
description: "test"

```
[0]
    icon: "assets/images/test1"
    name: "test"
[1]
    icon: "assets/images/test2.png"
    name: "test 2"
```

I am trying to loop through this array and display both the category name and the icon, however, displaying the icon isn't working.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of this.categories>
   {{category.name}}  
   <img src={{category.icon}}/>               
</ng-container>
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: For some reason this is now working - <img src="{{ category.icon }}" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an angular expert, but shouldn't you use the `[]` syntax for [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding)?

E.g.:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of this.categories">
   {{category.name}}  
   <img [src]="category.icon"/>               
</ng-container>
```

*Also, you're missing a `"` at the end of categories.*